# Customize command link button

Tags: winapi, button, win32gui

How to get rid of the green arrow in command link button (BS_COMMANDLINK)?

I know that the arrow can be changed to another image via BM_SETIMAGE, but how to get rid of the image entirely?

This is apparently possible as TaskDialogIndirect() provides such option for a custom button: TDF_USE_COMMAND_LINKS_NO_ICON.

**Edit:** I tried setting NULL bitmap or icon - this did not help: the arrow stays in place. Setting 1x1 transparent bitmap, e.g.:

```
    WORD bmp = 0xFF;
    HBITMAP hbmp = CreateBitmap(1, 1, 1, 1, &bmp);
    SendMessage(hbtn, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hbmp);
```

does work, but results in the left margin at least twice wider than in case of TaskDialogIndirect(), where the image is obviously not present at all.

**Solved:** I also tried different combinations of the button styles, hoping to find a magic one; looked into the button attributes by Spy++ – nothing helped! Then I returned back to bitmap and tried as the last resort “reverse” of NULL: -1 (xFFFF). And, bingo, this is it! Command link button without image:

```
    SendMessage(hbtn, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)-1);
```

Comment: _"arrow can be changed to another image via BM_SETIMAGE"_ -- Did you try to pass `NULL` for the icon/bitmap handle? If that doesn't work, try to assign a 1x1 transparent bitmap.

Comment: Yes I did try NULL for both Icon and Bitmap - does not work: the green arrow is still in place. Yes, 1x1 bitmap is the next obvious step, but I hoped there was a simpler solution...